# Remove TextBox Inner Padding?

Tags: wpf, textbox, padding

How can the *padding* (as shown in red) be removed from the TextBox?

[image]

Comment: You need to make a custom Style. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752068(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set negative values for padding.

e.g.

```
<TextBox  Padding="-2" Width="100" Height="18"></TextBox>
```

It will look like
[image]

Comment: You can adjust the padding as per your need.