# How to ensure that ListView shows complete items

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I've been following guidelines and [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186001/wpf-listview-always-show-complete-items) about how to fully show ListView items but it just doesn't work as expected. To demonstrate, I've created this very simple example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="textBox_PreviewMouseDown"  Text="5" />

        <Popup x:Name="popup"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
               Placement="Center"
               StaysOpen="False"
               >
            <ListView>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="5"/>
            </ListView>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This application shows a TextBox like this when started:

[image: TextBox]

When I click the TextBox, the popup opens and shows the ListView with 5 visible items:

[image]

Now as you can see, the middle item is not precisely covering the "5" in the TextBox, which is what I want. Also notice that the space under the last "5" in the list is not as much as it should be.

The Height of the ListView is a multiple of the ListViewItem and TextBox Height (5 * 30 = 150) which, in my understanding, should be the correct height.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong / missing - so that the middle "5" of the ListView is precisely covering the "5" in the TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wpf TextBox has some padding to provied space for letters like 'g' (sorry, don't know the right term for these extra pixels below baseline :-) )

So you may try adjust the padding of your Textbox like here : [TextBox Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908447/how-can-i-remove-inner-padding-on-textbox-wpf)

Do the entries need to be edited? If not, use a TextBlock instead with VerticalAlignment="Center". This shoud render nicer...

You may also define the datatemplate of your ListViewItem in your Style, I thinks it is "ContentPresenter" by default, Turning it to TextBox should render directly above.

And I would turn the TextBox's Visibility off, when showing the ListView. since the "middle" item could be '6'... If I'm right you're building some Scrolling selector for values..

EDIT:

after some testing, the ListView/ListBox Control have some internal paddings implemented. Unless you completely want to restyle them, your best shot will be setting the

```
HorizontalOffset=" -2"
VerticalOffset="-2"
```

of the popup control... or as needed. Hackish? Definitely :)

I guess you will use some Databindings too for your production code and this is just a design test now :)

Comment: But the issue is with ListView and ListViewItem (not the TextBox)? I can do some tricks to get it much nicer yes, but in the end, I really need to get the middle "5" in the ListView precisely over the "5" in the TextBox. And also understand how/why :)

Comment: Btw, just tried to put a ContentTemplate for the ListViewItem with a TextBlock in it. It shows 100% the same as my original issue unfortunately.

Comment: I guess that could be the solution. But as you say, it is hackish. For example on my screen the offset has to be -3. I'll wait to see if someone else has a solution that is both simple and production-mature. Thanks for helping out though, really appreciated!

Comment: @werner the values (-2,-2) resulted from using TextBlock as template. With TextBoxes this is (0,-3) as in you case, so that this is not (necesseraly) related to Screen resoultion, or similar issues, it results out of the control you use. But still, smells hacky :). As I said, you may restyle the ListView's ItemPanel, that could be the "real" solution

Comment: Yeah well, actually it seems to work on different devices. So, well done deal :) Thanks.

Comment: glad could help :)